# What is the Julia syntax for regex capture groups (e.g. $1 in Perl)?

Tags: regex, julia, capture-group

I wonder what is the Julia's equivalent of $1, $2, ... in Perl's regex (accessing substrings captured by regex)?

For instance

```
$s = "some random string";
$s =~ m/(o.e).+(i.g)/;
print $1, "\n", $2;
```

prints

```
ome
ing
```

Comment: what do you use $1 for in Perl?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the [Julia manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/) explains you can get captured substrings from `RegexMatch` object by either accessing its `captures` field or using `getindex`. For instance:

```
julia> s = "some random string"
"some random string"

julia> m = match(r"(o.e).+(i.g)", s)
RegexMatch("ome random string", 1="ome", 2="ing")

julia> m[1] # access using getindex
"ome"

julia> m[2]
"ing"

julia> m.captures
2-element Array{Union{SubString{String}, Void},1}:
 "ome"
 "ing"

julia> m = match(r"om", s) # no captured substrings
RegexMatch("om")

julia> m.captures
0-element Array{Union{SubString{String}, Void},1}

julia> m = match(r"ox", s)

julia> typeof(m) # no match, m is nothing
Void
```